# OAuth2 is not accessible from swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger, server-configuration

I am getting 401 when I try to access OAuth2 from swagger. It is working fine if Swagger is configured in same project and running on same port. But when I configure swagger in another project with different port then it gives 401.

OAuth2 is accessible and working fine with Postman. I am not able to find why it is giving 401 from different port. I have checked inbound/outbound rules of the running port. Is there any other configuration required for accessing OAuth from different server or port?

OAuth2 project is configured on http://localhost:8090/
SpringBoot project is configured on http://localhost:8888/ from where OAuth2 is giving 401.

WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
    /*
     * https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11136
     * Expose it manually (there is bug)
     *
     * */


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class CustomAuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "client";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "secret";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS = "client_credentials";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_AUTH_CODE = "authorization_code";

    private static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    private static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    private static final String SCOPE_TRUST = "trust";

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.tokenTimeout}")
    private int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.tokenTimeout}")
    private int REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.privateKey}")
    private String privateKey;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.publicKey}")
    private String publicKey;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS, GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN, GRANT_TYPE_AUTH_CODE)
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, SCOPE_TRUST)
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(CLIENT_SECRET));
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
    }
}
```

WebSecureConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class CustomResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {    
    @Value("${config.oauth2.publicKey}")
    private String publicKey;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.privateKey}")
    private String privateKey;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.resource.id}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/register", "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/**").authenticated();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources
                .resourceId(resourceId)
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe project needs some Cors configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In Swagger configuration , OAuth security schema should be properly initialized while creating Docket instance. Here Access Token URI is something like : http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token

```
@Value("${config.oauth2.accessTokenUri}")
private String accessTokenUri;


@Bean
public Docket productApi() {
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.authentication")).paths(regex("/.*"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()))
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(securitySchema()))
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}
```

```
private OAuth securitySchema() {

    List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = newArrayList();
    authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all"));
    authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("write", "access all"));

    List<GrantType> grantTypes = newArrayList();
    GrantType passwordCredentialsGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(accessTokenUri);
    grantTypes.add(passwordCredentialsGrant);

    return new OAuth("oauth2", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);
}

private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .build();
}
```